# How to parse TCP/IP packets from socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, parsing, packet

I have InputStream from socket `InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();`. I want to parse TCP/IP packets from this socket to get destination host and port.
How I can to do it?
Any advice?

### UPD

When printing out everything of the socket using:

```
bytes = sin.readAllBytes();
System.out.println("-> " + sin);
System.out.println("-> -> " + sin.read());
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("++ -> " + bytes[i]);
}
```

I have something like that:

```
-> java.net.SocketInputStream@36d64342
-> -> -1
++ -> 71
++ -> 69
++ -> 84
++ -> 32
++ -> 104
++ -> 116
++ -> 116
++ -> 112
++ -> 58
++ -> 47
++ -> 47
++ -> 50
++ -> 105
++ -> 112
++ -> 46
++ -> 114
++ -> 117
++ -> 47
++ -> 102
++ -> 97
++ -> 118
++ -> 105
++ -> 99
++ -> 111
++ -> 110
++ -> 46
++ -> 105
++ -> 99
++ -> 111
++ -> 32
++ -> 72
++ -> 84
++ -> 84
++ -> 80
++ -> 47
++ -> 49
++ -> 46
++ -> 49
++ -> 13
++ -> 10
++ -> 72
++ -> 111
++ -> 115
++ -> 116
++ -> 58
++ -> 32
++ -> 50
```

It's a piece of a byte array that i print.

### UPD2

When i convert bytes to char i have this one:

```
GET http://2ip.ru/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 2ip.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/
xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; M3s Build/LMY47I; wv)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.146     Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,en-US;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=enph0vckkk9t1hqaglch3b6693;
IP%5B1511541539%5D=96.94.32.50;
__gads=ID=88de3c23be0f84e7:T=1511541553:S
=ALNI_MZbnsWDJcRSBUodYKfLeCg9pjw
YQw; _ym_uid=1511541569449405305; 
IP%5B1511886512%5D=217.77.220.27;
__utma=260173902.2002453512.1511541552.1511886514.
1511953525.5;
__utmc=260173902; __utmz=260173902.1511541565.1.1.utmcsr
=(direct)|utmccn=    (direct)|utmcmd=(none)
X-Requested-With: com.vestasoft.vadim.proxynator
```

Comment: What do you mean by "packets"? TCP/IP packets?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Those bytes spell out "�GET http://2ip.ru/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 2".  It may be more useful to print the letters instead of the numbers (just cast each byte to char)

Comment: It looks good. But i don't have a port of host. Just a moment, i will update my question.

Comment: It looks like it wants "GET http://2ip.ru/ HTTP/1.1" and "Host: 2ip.ru".  Since there is no port specified, what happens if you try to use the default http port (80)?

Comment: It has no sense, but other websites can use another ports.

Comment: While websites are able to function on other ports besides 80, normally the port defaults to 80 if not specified.  Are you able to test other queries that you know are accessing a different port?

Comment: I'm tried. It's not working ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the host and port use

```
InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = (InetSocketAddress)socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
String host = remoteAddress.getHostName();
int port = remoteAddress.getPort();
```

The main thing you can do with the input stream from a socket is read it for data

If you have String data being transmitted, you can use a BufferedReader pretty easily

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
    //do stuff
```

Comment: Thx, but if I use getRemoteSocketAddress();, I have IP address of device, that connected to my server, but I want to get address of destination server.

Comment: @VadimNovakovskiy The local SocketAddress is `socket.getLocalSocketAddress();`, is there a 3rd address that you're looking for?

Comment: I have a device, that calling any website. My server catching TCP packets as a proxy server, and i want to get host and port, where do this packets go

Comment: @VadimNovakovskiy Have you tried printing out everything that is sent through the socket?  Are you defining your own protocol or using something else?